# Why my adb service is not starting? How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: android, adb

My android studio gives an error stating that my adb service is not starting. I tried finding the solution in the stackoverflow but didnt find any proper solution. Below is the screenshot of the problem. Kindly help, I have a project to complete.

[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: The data you provided does not allow us to solve your issue. Have you tried re-installing things?

Comment: If you have a project to complete, then why not read manuals and learn [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dell branded PC, this error can be occurred by Dell PC Suite. You need to uninstall it.